# Prevent upload shell files. php

Tags: php, shell, upload

I have image upload website. Someone is uploading here shells files.
My validations are:
- Check file's mime (only image's mimes able)
- Check if getimagesize returning array (by is_array)
If not, error.
And still, Someone is uploading shells files. Please help. Thnkas alot!

Little check:

```
$ext = ($_FILES['files']['type']); 

if (($ext != "image/jpeg") && ($ext != "image/pjpeg") && ($ext !="image/png") && ($ext != "image/gif") && ($ext != "image/bmp") && ($ext != "image/x-icon") && (!is_array(getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])))) {

    // Show error
} else {
    // Keep upload...
}
```

Comment: Besides the fact somebody can upload shells I wonder how they run them. Do you let people upload files in a public location?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the files permissions, the should not be executed by php.
It's easy to store data in the raster data matrix of an image (obviously).

Look at these innocent jellyfishes :

[image: Innocent jellyfishes]

Stackoverflow converted my innocent .BMP in a .PNG

The original .bmp can be found on [a friend's server](http://spartition.fr/jelly.bmp).
If you look in the bottom-left corner, you will see strange pixels, corresponding to ascii data written in the pixel data.

In order to avoid shell files, you should apply a modification which will alterate a little bit every pixel of the images.

To me, convertion (compression) seems a good start.

Good luck !

Comment: Ha ha. Same thing i did a while back. Only that i used a gif, as the first few bytes of gif is text and does not cause much problem with scripts.